# Full Calendar select: callback Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am currently trying to integrate fullcalendar into a project I am working on. I am running into some errors with the select: callback producing an error when trying to submit an ajax request. My select: callback looks like the following:

```
        select: function(start, end, allDay){
            var title = prompt('Event Title: ');
            if(title) {
                var start = jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                var end = jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                    data: {
                        action: 'add_itinerary_event',
                        JSToken: jQuery("#JSToken").val(),
                        GuestID: jQuery("#GuestID").val(),
                        Title: title,
                        Start: start,
                        End: end,
                        AllDay: allDay
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(json){
                        alert('Added Successfully');
                    }
                });
                itinerarycalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true);
            }
            itinerarycalendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
```

When adding an event to the calendar by selecting a time period, the console in Chrome records the following:

```
jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
at e (jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4)
at cc (jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4)
at cc (jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4)
at cc (jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4)
at cc (jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4)
at cc (jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4)
at Function.n.param (jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery-1.12.0.js?ver=4.7.4:4)
at Et.function.e.constructor.select (fitbscripts.js?ver=4.7.4:76)
at constructor.publiclyTrigger (fullcalendar.min.js?ver=4.7.4:9)
```

Clicking on the fitbscripts.js (the location of my code) points to the $.ajax line, but doesn't provide any further information.

In Safari, the following information is given:

```
[Error] TypeError: Can only call HTMLElement.click on instances of HTMLElement
click (jquery-1.12.0.js:4:24813)
e (jquery-1.12.0.js:4:24813)
cc (jquery-1.12.0.js:4:24698)
cc (jquery-1.12.0.js:4:24722)
cc (jquery-1.12.0.js:4:24722)
cc (jquery-1.12.0.js:4:24722)
param (jquery-1.12.0.js:4:25060)
ajax (jquery-1.12.0.js:4:20919)
select (fitbscripts.js:76)
publiclyTrigger (fullcalendar.min.js:9:16488)
publiclyTrigger (fullcalendar.min.js:8:30679)
triggerSelect (fullcalendar.min.js:9:8211)
reportSelection (fullcalendar.min.js:9:8156)
interactionEnd (fullcalendar.min.js:7:19556)
trigger (fullcalendar.min.js:7:7856)
handleInteractionEnd (fullcalendar.min.js:7:6113)
handleInteractionEnd (fullcalendar.min.js:7:11377)
endInteraction (fullcalendar.min.js:7:6045)
d (jquery-1.12.0.js:2:3862)
n (fullcalendar.min.js:6:31915)
dispatch (jquery-1.12.0.js:3:12350)
handle (jquery-1.12.0.js:3:9077)
trigger (jquery-1.12.0.js:3:11477)
triggerHandler (jquery-1.12.0.js:3:18984)
trigger (fullcalendar.min.js:7:145)
handleMouseUp (fullcalendar.min.js:7:13137)
d (jquery-1.12.0.js:2:3862)
dispatch (jquery-1.12.0.js:3:12350)
handle (jquery-1.12.0.js:3:9077)
```

Does anyone know what may be causing this? I seem to be going around in circles trying to find out what is happening here.

Comment: Hi! What jquery, fullcalendar versions do you use?

Comment: Fullcalendar v3.4.0, jQuery 1.12.0

Comment: @LakiGeri I have updated to jQuery 2.1.0, as it looks like fullcalendar requires 2.0+, however I am receiving the same error messages.

Comment: Interesting.. what is the sequence of the import? The wrong order can cause problem

Comment: first make sure you've included everything, in the right order, as shown here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ and verify in your network tab that the files are actually loaded sucessfully into the page. Equally, also ensure you haven't loaded any of those dependencies _more than once_ (you'd be surprised how often I see that). Once all of that is verified, if the problem is still there then it's worth doing more investigation.

Comment: Hey Matt, any update on this? running into this issue now (with jQuery 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the problem by using native JS ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  data: {
    action: 'add_itinerary_event',
    JSToken: 'xyz'
  },
  type: 'post',
  success: function(json){
    alert('Added Successfully');
  }
});
```

... becomes ...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken); // if needed
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    alert('Added Successfully: ', JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
  }
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
  action: 'add_itinerary_event',
  JSToken: 'xyz'
}));
```

I know that's only a workaround, but it's helped me move forward with fullcalendar.